# How can I build an array of unique Objects based on an object's property in a Promise in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I've tried many things and I can't get around this problem.

I have this piece of code:

```
matches => {
            matches.forEach(match => {
              match.away = this.teamService.getTeam(match._links.awayTeam.href);
              match.home = this.teamService.getTeam(match._links.homeTeam.href);
              match.away.then(away => this.teams.indexOf(away) === -1 ? this.teams.push(away) : console.log("This item already exists"));
              match.home.then(home => this.teams.indexOf(home) === -1 ? this.teams.push(home) : console.log("This item already exists"));
            });
            return matches;
          }
```

I retrieved a list of all matches from a competition from an API, and each match has a link to a home team and an away team:

```
match._links.awayTeam.href
```

the getTeam() method returns a Promise Team

```
getTeam(id: string): Promise<Team> {
    return this.http.get(id)
           .toPromise()
           .then(response => response.json() as Team)
           .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

So what I need is to build an array of teams that participated in the matches in scope. To be more specific, I need to build an array of unique Teams to determine a list of the **participant teams in the competition**.

Anyway, I'm printing the list as this:

```
<md-list>
    <md-list-item *ngFor="let team of teams">
        <button md-raised-button>{{team.teamName}}</button>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

And the result is list of each team in each match:

```
Team 1 vs Team 2
Team 2 vs Team 1
```

Result:

```
Team 1 
Team 2 
Team 1 
Team 2
```

I'm using angular 4, and I would like to avoid importing more libraries.

I think it has something to do with resolving the promises within the forEach before comparing and building the array but I can't get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, at first, If I were you I'd store all observables in an `array`(without subscribe) and use **`Observable.forkJoin([...])`** to perform some operation a single time (in your case: distinct the values in the array)... or even consider doing a single request? Ex: `http://myapi.com?some_key=list_of_href_or_whatever`. For sure, any of these approaches will improve the response time. Actually (the way that you're doing), if you have **n** "matches", you'll send **n*2** requests.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question 100%, but the native Array.filter() method is great for finding uniques. It takes a callback that return a boolean, and it returns a new array including every item the callback returned true for.

```
const makeTeamFilter = (names = {}) => (team) => {
     names[team.name] = names[team.name] ? names[team.name] + 1 : 1;
     return names[team.name] === 1;
};
teams.filter(makeTeamFilter());
```